# Can we convert the structure "Noun 1 + Preposition + Noun 2" into "Noun 1 is / are Preposition + Noun 2"?

Tags: word-usage, prepositions, sentence-structure

Ok, see [the definition](https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/investment?q=investment) of **investment**

> [uncountable] the act of investing money in something
>
> *to encourage foreign investment*
>
> *investment income*
>
> **investment in something** *This country needs investment in education.*

See the example "*This country needs investment in education.*",

my question is:

can we change "**We have an investment in education**" to "**We have an 
 investment that is in education**"?

or "**This is the book for you**" to "**This is the book that is for you**"

or "**I have an investment of 5000 USD**" to "**I have an investment that is of 5000 USD**"

or "**We met on a flight from London to Paris.**" to "**We met on the flight that is from London to Paris**"

and many more examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, we can replace the prepositional phrase that modifies the noun it follows with a restrictive subordinate clause that modifies that noun; in some cases the prepositional phrase is a little "iffy", not immediately clear, and would be clearer if expressed as a clause:

> We met on a flight from London to Paris.
>
> We met on a flight that goes from London to Paris.

Such prepositional phrases can attach to a constituent other than the immediately preceding noun:

> We walked into the room with our eyes closed.

In some cases that flexibility can result in a momentary confusion or ambiguity that would not have occurred had the idea been expressed with a clause.

> She looked at the child with wide eyes.